# Dynamic library definition in data step view

Tags: view, sas

In a proc sql view, it is possible to utilise a temporary library definition as per syntax below:

```
libname viewlib 'SAS-data-library'; 

proc sql;
   create view viewlib.emp_view as
      select * 
         from mydblib.employees
         using libname mydblib oracle user=smith password=secret 
            path='myoraclepath';
quit;
```

A useful advantage of this approach is that it allows the SAS/Access credentials (eg password etc) to remain hidden, and also will not conflict with existing library definitions (eg if the user already had a 'mydblib' libref, this does not replace that definition).

However there are certain criteria under which SQL views are not appropriate - such as when trying to restrict automatic SQL pass through, or  creating views on text files.

My question then, is - what is the best way to create a **data step view**, using a temporary libref such as the SQL view example above?  The libref should not conflict with existing librefs, should not persist in the user session, and should not allow passwords etc to be visible..

Comment: I don't think there's a solution for relational DBs.  I'm curious though, why do you want a solution that's not a sql view?  What's wrong with a sql view?  What situation would suggest a data step view?

Comment: I need to restrict the SQL pass-through.  Specifically, the native database I am testing against, cannot perform SORTs.  This database does not have a dedicated ACCESS engine, it is piggy-backing on the MySQL engine.  I think you're right - there is no (base SAS) solution for relational DBs..

Comment: So you need to force it to sort in SAS rather than in SQL/DB?

Comment: exactly.  However libname option SQLGENERATION=NONE is not available for MYSQL, and DIRECT_SQL=NONE still passes back the sort option.  Global option SORTPGM=SAS only applies to proc sort..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - it IS possible.  Got there in the end!

```
%let templib=SomeLib4;
data myview /view=myview;
attrib   var1  format=$32767. informat=$32767. label='blah'
   var2  format=$32767. informat=$32767. label='blah'
   var3  format=$32767. informat=$32767. label='blah';
call missing(of _all_); /* avoid initialisation log messages */
if libref("&templib")=0 then do;
    put "WARNING: Library &templib already exists, terminating..";
    stop; /* do not replace an existing libref */
end;
else __rc=libname("&templib",,'MYSQL',  
    "SERVER='blah.com'  MYSQL_PORT=3306  DATABASE=blah  
    USER='blah'  PASSWORD='xxx' "); /* Declare temporary libref */
__DSID=OPEN("&templib..MY_Dataset",'IS'); /* OPEN the data set */ 
CALL SET(__DSID); /* use CALL SET to get variable values */ 
__rc=FETCH(__DSID); /* FETCH the first observation */ 
DO WHILE (__rc=0); /* while the last FETCH retrieved an obs */ 
    OUTPUT; /* OUTPUT an observation */ 
    __rc=FETCH(__DSID); /* FETCH the next observation */ 
END; 
__rc=CLOSE(__DSID); /* CLOSE the data set */ 
__rc=libname("&templib"); /* CLOSE the temporary libref */
stop;
drop __rc __DSID ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly reference a file by path, if that's what you're looking for.  I don't know if this is helpful for your specific example as I don't know that this is going to work with a non-SAS dataset, but it's probably a good idea to have this answer for googlers as it's a reasonable answer to your title question.

For example:

```
libname ctest 'c:\temp';

data ctest.myview/view=ctest.myview;
set 'c:\AnotherLocation\class';
run;
```

Sample data:

```
data 'c:\AnotherLocation\class';
set sashelp.class;
run;
```

However, this won't work with a relational database.

As far as text files, while this doesn't work, you can create a view off of an infile; assume 'c:\temp\dummy.txt' exists with some text in it:

```
data testvw/view=testvw;
infile "c:\temp\dummy.txt" lrecl=50 pad truncover;
input 
@1 str $50.;
run;
```

Run, inspect; then add some lines of text.  Then reopen the view - it will be updated.

Comment: A preferable approach, if not using relational DB's!  Upvoted.